# Creating a node angular app

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular, mean-stack, mean

I`m creating a node angular app. As i identified there are two ways.

1. As a single app. So it is a node project and angular folder (client) is inside it. So the file structure is advance.
2. As two separate apps. So angular app and node app are separate and angular app get data using the url of node app. here the file structure is more understandable and easy to code.

can anyone explain me what is the better way.

Comment: Are you referring to your folder structure or to the architecture of your system?

Comment: no I think he is talking about serving his app

Comment: yes. I`m talking about serving my app. because keeping two of them separately is more understandable and readable in later time by other developers and also by me. but as I refered many of the tutorials do in other way.

Comment: I would suggest you the second one as it is more manageable later on you can integrate the two builds if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Development.

The Node and Angular projects should be separate. Each of the projects has its own package.json. Start the Node app (e.g. on port 8000) with configured REST endpoints - it'll be returning JSON.

Start the client using Angular CLI ng serve, which will start the dev server on port 4200. To access the data server on port 8000 from your Angular app that runs on 4200 you'll need to configure a small proxy-conf file so the browser won't be giving you CORS errors. For example, if your Node app has an endpoint /api/products, create a file proxy-conf.json in your Angular project:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8000",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

Now you can continue Angular coding against the dev server, but the data will be coming from the Node server:

```
ng serve --proxy-config proxy-conf.json
```

Deployment.

Using Express API, define the folder on your Node server that will contain static content (your Angular bundles and resources).

Build the bundles using ng build and copy the content of your dist dir into that static dir on the node app.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you're talking about a typical MEAN stack web app, the front-end is Angular and the back-end is Node with Express and a database (Mongodb), or any similar libraries.

There's no better way. It really depends on your application. There are various ways you can serve your app. You should build your angular app and take your static files and serve them from anywhere you like.

1. You can serve them through the same server you're using as a back-end. Just place the files node's static folder and tell node to serve them. This is a nice and a quick way and works quite well.
2. You can make a separate server for the front-end and use a more robust files server such as nginx or apache or maybe even another node server. This is nice if you have two servers and want to take away the front-end's bandwidth load from your back-end server.
3. If your front-end is Angular**2** you can use its built-in lite server (by issuing `ng serve`). This is mostly used for development and is a big overhead on your server but it works. You can do this on a separate server.

---

You've mentioned in comments that you care about other developers understanding your project. Probably I would go with jitender. There's no reason for you to combine the code and keeping them separate is probably a good thing if you want to move your project from a server to another. So for example if you were serving the front-end from the same back-end server but decided to add a dedicated front-end server later on.

Also sometimes you would want to add a separate front-end beside your original. For example if you want to add a mobile app, it would communicate with the same back-end server. There's no reason to make the same back-end server serve the Angular app.

Comment: I think this you don't get the question he is asking about the structure instead

Comment: He said in a comment above that he's talking about serving his app. "
yes. I`m talking about serving my app." @jitender

Answer (score 1):

Both has its own advantages but if the application is heavy create the client app(angular) and the server app(express or koa js) separately. Separation of client and server app  is always better when it comes to maintainance and scaling